# Pandas conditionally copying of cell value by column and index

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.6

I want to copy the cell from one by row and column. I.e if Country is GB, I want to copy Col2, to Country FR COL 2. Using pandas

**Pseudo**

```
If (Country == "GB") then:
    Copy Col2 from GB to FR COL2
```

**Example**

```
Country Col1   Col2
GB       4       5
FR       2       x
GB       1       6
FR       7       x
GB       2       8
CN       3       x
```

result should be

```
Country Col1   Col2
GB       4       5
FR       2       5
GB       1       6
FR       7       6
GB       2       8
CN       3       x
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your pseudo code: there are multiple `GB` and `FR` values, do you want the `GB` value to be inserted into only the next `FR`? only if `GB` and `FR` are consecutive?

Comment: I want it to copy all  `GB` `Col2` to`FR`  `Col 2`, doesn't have to be consecutive.

Comment: @Ant You still need some criteria. Why are you in your result doing it that way and not backwards for instance.

Comment: @Anton vBr Becuase I want to be able to copy any values from `GB` `Col2` to `FR` `COL2.`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way that achieves your result (assuming FR < GB). Hopefully it can help you further/solve your problem.

```
m = df['Country'] == 'FR'
df.loc[m,'Col2'] = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'GB','Col2'].values[:sum(m)]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Country Col1   Col2
GB       4       5
FR       2       x
GB       1       6
FR       7       x
GB       2       8
CN       3       x'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

# Mask
m = df['Country'] == 'FR'

#Assign
df.loc[m,'Col2'] = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'GB','Col2'].values[:sum(m)]

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  Country  Col1 Col2
0      GB     4    5
1      FR     2    5
2      GB     1    6
3      FR     7    6
4      GB     2    8
5      CN     3    x
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
df.loc[(df['Country'] == 'FR') & (df['Col2'].isnull()) 
      & (df['Country'].shift(1) == 'GB'), 'Col2'] = df['Col2'].shift(1)
```

or this:

```
df.loc[(df['Country'] == 'FR') 
      & (df['Country'].shift(1) == 'GB'), 'Col2'] = df['Col2'].shift(1)
```